# subtracting a negative 2's complement

Tags: binary, twos-complement, number-systems

I have two 2's complement signed binary numbers and want to subtraction them (assuming an 8-bit subtractor)

1001 0110

1000 0001

what would be the operation to find the difference and why/whynot is there an overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the difference between 2 numbers you have to subtract them:
`1001 0110b = -106`
`1000 0001b = -127`
so `-106 - (-127) = 21`

you can also do that in binary:

```
 1001 0110b
-1000 0001b
     =
 0001 0101b
```

another method is: `a-b = a+(-b)`, so you have to make the 2's complement of the second number. So `1000 0001b` becomes `0111 1111b`.

```
  1001 0110b
 +0111 1111b
      =
1 0001 0101b
```

the first `1` doesn't count because it's a 8bit number, so the result is also `0001 0101b` which is 21 in decimal.

Comment: How to calculate -1-1?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil `1111 1111b` - `0000 0001b` = `1111 1110b` ==> `-2`.